# How to setup Eclipse for Android

Tags: android, eclipse, installation

I'm trying to get Eclipse setup for Android and have done the following steps. I'm using the book "Android 101" and basically following the steps.
(1) Installed Java SDK
(2) Installed Eclipse
(3) Installed Android SDK

I start Eclipse and go to Window->Preferences and expect to see Android in the list. I'm supposed to select Android then point it to where I installed the Android SDK. The problem is that I'm not seeing Android in the list.

I did not have any trouble with the Java or Android installs, and I didn't see any option in the Eclipse install specific to Android.

I've searched on Stack Overflow and Googled, and am not finding anything.

Comment: Note that official Eclipse support is ending in ~75 days. IMHO, you will be better served starting with Android Studio, rather than having to struggle with a semi-supported IDE.

Answer (score 1):

From inside Eclipse select Help->Install New Software then click NEW.

Install ADT from https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse

After that you point it to your Android SDK install location and the APIs all show up. Hit APPLY and OK, then ready to start working.

Answer (score 0):

The best plan here is to follow the [advice](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html) given on the Android Developers blog in June, 2015.

> […] we are ending development and official support for the Android Developer Tools (ADT) in Eclipse at the end of the year. This specifically includes the Eclipse ADT plugin and Android Ant build system. If you have not had the chance to migrate your projects to Android Studio, now is the time.

I'm a long-time Eclipse user, and I recently fired up Android Studio for some brief Android testing. There was definitely a learning curve, but it wasn't insurmountable.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I think I'll use Eclipse/Android at least through a few tutorials and a Hello World app or two since I've gone to all this trouble to get it installed and running. After that I'll try Android Studio since that is what is now supported.